# TransformXml could not be loaded in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-pipelines

I've got a console app in VS 2019 to which I added the TransformXml task, and it builds fine locally. However, in the Devops pipeline, it throws "TransformXml task could not be loaded" error.

> C:__w\1\s\Sith\SithWatchDog\SithWatchDog.csproj(138,4): error MSB4062: The "TransformXml" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.403\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.403\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll'. The system cannot find the path specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Here's the task I added to the csproj file.

```
    <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
    <Target Name="ApplyConfigurationConfigFile" AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild" Condition="Exists('App.$(Configuration).config')">
      <ItemGroup>
        <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="App.config" />
        <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config">
          <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
        </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
      </ItemGroup>
      <TransformXml Source="App.config" Destination="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config" Transform="App.$(Configuration).config" />
    </Target>
```

In my local machine, Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll is installed in this path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll`. In the Devops pipeline I have no idea where it's installed. Is there a way to find out where Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll is installed in the pipeline? Or is there another way to apply the TransformXml in the pipeline?

Update (2/2/2024):
After Wade's comment, I ended up updating my csproj file as follow. Notice that I had to account for VS2019 and VS2022 because their MSBuild paths are different.

```
...
    <PropertyGroup Condition="!Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll')">
        <MSBuildExtensionsPath32>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild</MSBuildExtensionsPath32>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="!Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll')">
        <MSBuildExtensionsPath32>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild</MSBuildExtensionsPath32>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
    <Target Name="ApplyConfigurationConfigFile" AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild" Condition="Exists('App.$(Configuration).config')">
      <ItemGroup>
        <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="App.config" />
        <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config">
          <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
        </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
      </ItemGroup>
      <TransformXml Source="App.config" Destination="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config" Transform="App.$(Configuration).config" />
    </Target>
  </Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assemblyfile `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll` exists in the MSBuild directory of your Visual Studio installation. The exact path can vary depending on the `version of Visual Studio` you are using.

**On VS2022**: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll

**On VS2019**: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebMicrosoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll

You need to check **which VS version** installed on your DevOps agent. To confirm the file path in DevOps pipeline, you can use PowerShell task below( x86 path for VS2019 on my side):

```
pool:
  vmImage: Windows-2019

- powershell: |
    Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio" -Include Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

[image]

As per your error message, it appears you are using self-hosted agent, and assemblyfile cannot be found due to $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) property is not resolving to the correct path.

1. As per the version `v17.0` in the error, it appears you are using VS2022 not VS2019, please confirm this on the agent. Use `V16.0` for VS2019.
2. `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)` points to incorrect path `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.403`, it should point to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise` on VS2019. Change path accordingly if you use VS2022.